# Method outside template class with enable_if

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code where I want a template class to check the template value as one of `int64_t` or `unint64_t` upon init. The class has a `GetValue` method that is implemented outside the class.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int64_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>>::type>
class Class
{
public:
    Class(T value) noexcept :
        cachedValue(value) {}

    T GetValue() noexcept;

private:
    T cachedValue;
};

template <typename T>
T Class<T>::GetValue() noexcept
{
    // placeholder for now.
    return cachedValue;
}
```

However, I am running into build errors `C2955`, `C2956`, `C2976` or something similar from the `enable_if` even after trying several ideas from other SO posts. How do I get this working?

Comment: Did one of those several-ideas [look anything like this](https://godbolt.org/z/K4EeM4) ?

Comment: It seems you want to disable instantiating `Class` if `T` is neither `int64_t` nor `uint64_t`.
Just put `static_assert()` with the condition from `enable_if` into your class.

Comment: @WhozCraig That works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with

```
template <typename T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int64_t>
                               || std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>>::type>
class Class;
```

is that is result into

```
template <typename T_OK, void> class Class;
```

or

```
template <typename T_KO, /*Subsitution failure*/> class Class;
```

Which are both incorrect.

For non-friendly cases, (which might be enough most of the time), you might simply use `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T> class Class
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int64_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>);
    /// ...
};
```

Else there are several variation (I will shorter the condition to `cond_v<T>`)

- Common one :( :

  ```
  template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>>>
  class Class
  {
      /// ...
  };
  Class<int64_t> ok;
  Class<float> ko; // doesn't compile, as expected
  // but might be hijacked:
  Class<float, void> hijacked; // compile, unexpected
  ```
- Fixed:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>, int> = 0>
  class Class
  {
      /// ...
  };
  Class<int64_t> ok;
  Class<float> ko; // doesn't compile, as expected
  ```
- One which allow customization

  ```
  template <typename T, typename = void>
  class Class;

  template <typename T>
  class Class<T, std::enable_if_t<cond_v<T>>>
  {
      /// ...
  };
  Class<int64_t> ok;
  Class<float> ko; // incomplete type: doesn't compile, as expected

  // user might add additional specialization:
  template <typename T>
  class Class<std::vector<T>, void> {/*..*/};
  ```

  mostly useful to create customizable traits (as you specialize whole class).

C++20 introduces concept which shorter and simplify syntax:

- restreint allowed type (there are several equivalent syntax)

  ```
  template <typename T> requires(cond_v<T>)
  class Class { /*..*/};
  ```
- Allow customization, take best specialization:

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class Class;

  // Specialization
  template <typename T> requires(cond_v<T>)
  class Class<T> { /*..*/};
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided to stick with the comment by WhozCraig and also keep the enable_if for now. Although I may adapt the customization you mentioned if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @WhozCraing method, use a `static_assert` to provide some message/instruction or use `Concepts` with `C++20`, as follows

```
template<class T>
concept ints64 = std::is_same_v<T, int64_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>;
template <typename T> requires(ints64<T>)
struct Class{
    Class(T value) noexcept : cachedValue(value) {}
    T GetValue() noexcept;

private:
    T cachedValue;
};

template <typename T>requires(ints64<T>)
T Class<T>::GetValue() noexcept{
    return cachedValue;
}

int main(){
    return Class<int64_t>{0}.GetValue();//return Class<int>{0}.GetValue(); won't compile

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also a traditional way to make class template SFINAE-friendly before C++20:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename = void>
class Class; // <1> you can define it here if the conditions are not satisfied.

template<typename T>
class Class<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, int64_t> || std::is_same_v<T, uint64_t>>::type>{
public:
    Class(T value) noexcept :cachedValue(value) {}

    T GetValue() noexcept;

private:
    T cachedValue;
};

int main(){
    Class<int64_t> a = 0; // ok
    Class<uint64_t> b = 0; // ok
    Class<int32_t> c = 0; // incomplete-type. you can define it at <1>.
}
```